# Python-Selenium error: StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium with python,
my main function calls are:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
admin = AdminActions()

admin.log_in_as_admin(driver, actions)
admin.create_test_user(driver, actions)
admin.delete_test_user(driver, actions)
admin.log_out_from_admin(driver, actions)
```

................................................................................

my problem is, that if I'm running it separatedly like:

```
admin.log_in_as_admin(driver, actions)
admin.log_out_from_admin(driver, actions)
```

or

```
admin.log_in_as_admin(driver, actions)
admin.create_test_user(driver, actions)
```

etc... but when i try to run more, like

```
admin.log_in_as_admin(driver, actions)
admin.create_test_user(driver, actions)
admin.delete_test_user(driver, actions)
admin.log_out_from_admin(driver, actions)
```

it throws an exeption message: Element not found in the cache.

Here's the AdminActions class:

class AdminActions():

```
def log_in_as_admin(self, driver, actions):
    driver.get("http://192.168.30.128:8080/reviewboard/account/login/?next=/reviewboard/dashboard/")
    user_name = driver.find_element_by_id("id_username").send_keys("admin")
    user_pwd = driver.find_element_by_id("id_password").send_keys("adminpwd")
    log_in_menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"login_form\"]/div[3]/div/input").click()

def create_test_user(self, driver, actions):
    driver.get("http://192.168.30.128:8080/reviewboard/dashboard/")
    user_menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accountnav"]/li[2]/a')
    admin_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accountnav"]/li[2]/ul/li[2]/a')
    actions.move_to_element(user_menu).click(admin_button).perform()
    add_user_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="widget-manage"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a/div').click()
    user_name = driver.find_element_by_id("id_username").send_keys("test_user")
    user_password = driver.find_element_by_id("id_password1").send_keys("secret_password")
    user_password = driver.find_element_by_id("id_password2").send_keys("secret_password")
    review_type_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_schedule_set-0-reviewtypes_0"]').click()
    review_type_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_schedule_set-0-reviewtypes_1"]').click()
    review_type_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_schedule_set-0-reviewtypes_2"]').click()
    review_type_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_schedule_set-0-reviewtypes_3"]').click()
    review_type_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_schedule_set-0-reviewtypes_4"]').click()
    review_type_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_schedule_set-0-reviewtypes_5"]').click()
    review_type_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_schedule_set-0-reviewtypes_6"]').click()
    review_type_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_schedule_set-0-reviewtypes_7"]').click()
    review_type_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_schedule_set-0-reviewtypes_8"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user_form"]/div/div[2]/input[1]').click()

def delete_test_user(self, driver, actions):
    driver.get("http://192.168.30.128:8080/reviewboard/dashboard/")
    user_menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accountnav"]/li[2]/a')
    admin_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accountnav"]/li[2]/ul/li[2]/a')
    actions.move_to_element(user_menu).click(admin_button).perform()
    users_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="widget-manage"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/th/a')
    users_button.click()
    search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id("searchbar")
    search_bar.send_keys("test_user")
    search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="changelist-search"]/div/input[2]')
    search_button.click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="changelist-form"]/div[1]/label/select/option[2]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="result_list"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/input').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="changelist-form"]/div[1]/button').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/form/div/input[4]').click()            

def log_out_from_admin(self, driver, actions):
    driver.get("http://192.168.30.128:8080/reviewboard/dashboard/")
    quit_menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accountnav"]/li[2]/a')
    quit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accountnav"]/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a')
    actions.move_to_element(quit_menu).click(quit_button).perform()
```

Comment: why you use `ActionChains` ? as far as I know this method allow to collect some actions in queue and then execute all actions together with `.perform()` What is the purpose of using `ActionChains` in your case? And what is the `AdminActions` ? This is not a `Selenium` method.. If it is your class, then show its code also

Comment: Could you try putting a sleep before trying to find that element. The problem might be that the element is deleted entirely or the element is no longer attached to the dom. In some edge cases the element changes, but the keeps the same locator semantic. So add a Thread.sleep(5000) before admin.delete_test_user(driver, actions)

Comment: I tried the Thread.sleep(int) function as you (Madis Kangro) told me, sadly, It ain't help, it waits and than sends the same error message.

Comment: what exact element can not be found? can you add full error log to understand on what stage error occurs?

Comment: Hey, here is my error: http://pastebin.com/PS3vgmsp

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an explicit wait to retry with a `try..except` block as shown below to handle `StaleElementReferenceException`.

```
for i in xrange(30):
    try:
      --> line of code throwing the exception <--
      break
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
      print 'attempting to recover from StaleElementReferenceException ...'
      time.sleep(1)
```